# RuntimeError: The layer sequential_3 has never been called and thus has no defined input

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, lstm

I am training a neural network with 1 lstm layer and 3 Dense layer. But when I am trying to access the input tensors from the model using model.get_input_at(0), the code is giving this error.

"RuntimeError: The layer sequential_3 has never been called and thus has no defined input."

Here is the code:

```
# Define the LSTM model using Keras
model = Sequential()
model.add(Input(shape=(150, 1)))
model.add(LSTM(150)) 
model.add(Dense(150))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(100))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))  
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

# Train the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=32, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))

# Save the model
model.save("/content/drive/MyDrive/vm_data/cpu_model_smaller_ranges_15min_1.h5")

# 1st layer is LSTM layer with output shape (Batch_Size, 32)
lstm = model.layers[0]

# Get output from intermediate layer to visualize activations
attn_func = K.function(inputs = [model.get_input_at(0), K.learning_phase()],
           outputs = [lstm.output]
          )
```

And the Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-100-0f83ef6a34e7> in <cell line: 5>()
      3 
      4 # Get output from intermediate layer to visualize activations
----> 5 attn_func = K.function(inputs = [model.get_input_at(0), K.learning_phase()],
      6            outputs = [lstm.output]
      7           )

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/base_layer.py in _get_node_attribute_at_index(self, node_index, attr, attr_name)
   2976         """
   2977         if not self._inbound_nodes:
-> 2978             raise RuntimeError(
   2979                 f"The layer {self.name} has never been called "
   2980                 f"and thus has no defined {attr_name}."

RuntimeError: The layer sequential_3 has never been called and thus has no defined input.
```

I have replaced model.get_input_at(0) with model.layers[0].input but getting this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-101-66899e9b6e26> in <cell line: 5>()
      3 
      4 # Get output from intermediate layer to visualize activations
----> 5 attn_func = K.function(inputs = [model.layers[0].input, K.learning_phase()],
      6            outputs = [lstm.output]
      7           )

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/backend.py in function(inputs, outputs, updates, name, **kwargs)
   4652         from keras.src import models
   4653 
-> 4654         model = models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
   4655 
   4656         wrap_outputs = isinstance(outputs, list) and len(outputs) == 1

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/trackable/base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    202     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    203     try:
--> 204       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    205     finally:
    206       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/functional.py in __init__(self, inputs, outputs, name, trainable, **kwargs)
    156         if tf.compat.v1.executing_eagerly_outside_functions():
    157             if not all(
--> 158                 [
    159                     functional_utils.is_input_keras_tensor(t)
    160                     for t in tf.nest.flatten(inputs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/functional.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    157             if not all(
    158                 [
--> 159                     functional_utils.is_input_keras_tensor(t)
    160                     for t in tf.nest.flatten(inputs)
    161                 ]

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/functional_utils.py in is_input_keras_tensor(tensor)
     46     """
     47     if not node_module.is_keras_tensor(tensor):
---> 48         raise ValueError(_KERAS_TENSOR_TYPE_CHECK_ERROR_MSG.format(tensor))
     49     return tensor.node.is_input
     50 

ValueError: Found unexpected instance while processing input tensors for keras functional model. Expecting KerasTensor which is from tf.keras.Input() or output from keras layer call(). Got: 0
```

What is the cause of these errors?